# How to insert a node in Linked List using java?

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying this method but I can't figure out the problem. I think that there is some problem in insert() method because I have not used recursion but i can't exactly pinpoint it.
Thanks in advance.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;
    Node(int d) {
        data = d;
        next = null;
    }
}

class Solution {
public static  Node insert(Node head,int data) {
        //Some problem in this method
        if(head==null)
            return new Node(data);
        else{
            Node nxt = head;
            while(nxt!=null)
                nxt = nxt.next;
            nxt = new Node(data);
            return head;
        }
    }
    public static void display(Node head) {
        Node start = head;
        while(start != null) {
            System.out.print(start.data + " ");
            start = start.next;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Node head = null;
        int N = sc.nextInt();

        while(N-- > 0) {
            int ele = sc.nextInt();
            head = insert(head,ele);
        }
        display(head);
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `nxt` is loose, it's not connected to anything!

Answer (score 2):

Try with the below code.

```
class Nodes {
  int data;
  Nodes next;

  Nodes(int data) {
    this.data = data;
  }
}


/**
 * Insert in linkedList
 * 
 * @author asharda
 *
 */
public class LinkedListSum {


  public Nodes insert(Nodes node, int data) {
    Nodes temp;
    if (node == null) {
      node = new Nodes(data);
      return node;
    } else {
      temp = node;
      while (temp.next != null) {
        temp = temp.next;
      }
      temp.next = new Nodes(data);
      return node;
    }
  }// end of insert

  /**
   * Display LinkedList
   * 
   * @param root
   */
  public void display(Nodes root) {
    while (root != null) {
      System.out.println(root.data);
      root = root.next;
    }
  }

  /**
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedListSum sum = new LinkedListSum();
    Nodes head = null;
    head = sum.insert(head, 3);
    head = sum.insert(head, 1);
    head = sum.insert(head, 5);
    sum.display(head);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do

```
 nxt = new Node(data);
```

That won't actually alter the list - it'll just make `nxt` refer to a new Node instead of the node at the end of the list. You actually want to do

```
 nxt.next = new Node(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

when inserting a new Node, `next` **of previous** Node must be set to this new Node - `nxt = new Node(data)` *only* sets the variable. Hint: end the loop when `next` of the node is `null` instead of the node being `null` (rename the loop variable from `nxt` to `node` or `last`) and set its `next` to the new Node.

In other words, find the last node and set its `next` to the new node.

Suggested improvement: instead of returning the head of the list, just save it as a field of the list class. Initially it is null and set to the first node that is inserted. This avoids you haven't to maintain it outside of the list...